# How to include header files in CMakeLists.txt in Qt Creator?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator to learn C++, not using anything of Qt library, I am just using the IDE. I created a header file but it keeps saying:

> this file is not part of any project

I know it must be something to the CMakeLists.txt but I can't figure out how to do it, or why it did not include automatically.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    
project(S13V140_implementing_member_method)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

Answer (score 1):

For CMake and Qt to work together make sure you add **all** your headers to the list of source files.

```
set(sources "main.cpp" "my_header.h")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${sources})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CMakeLists.txt should work for you:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# define the project name
project(S13V140_implementing_member_method)

# find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# C++11 support - else we run into issues with the non-static nullptr-assignment
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# put all sources into one variable: no distinction between h, cpp and ui (or qrc)
set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

# create the final result
add_executable(S13V140_implementing_member_method ${SOURCES})
```